# How to forward SSL CONNECT requests (not intercept) on a school project proxy

Tags: c#, ssl, proxy

I'm writing a basic HTTP proxy for a school project using HttpWebRequest HttpWebResponse. It's all working great for HTTP requests, but when it comes to receiving a HTTPS request it fails miserably.

I don't want the proxy to intercept and decrypt HTTPS traffic, merely just pass it along. I know I could just change the proxy server settings in windows to only handle HTTP traffic, but I'd really like to try and handle it some way. How can this be done?

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to communicate with the proxy with HTTP, issue a CONNECT request and then pass through the TLS traffic - which is the usual way to do for client-to-server HTTPS via proxy. Or do you want to communicate with the proxy with HTTPS, i.e. encryption between client and proxy and inside the other encryption between client and server?

Comment: I think the easiest way for me to describe what i'm after is if you were to do the following: Set your IE proxy server (HTTPS) settings to localhost:8080, have a TcpListener running on port 8080, and when a browser tries to access a web address, forward the request. Like a transparent proxy of sorts I guess.

Comment: *"Like a transparent proxy of sorts I guess."* - this is not a transparent proxy but an explicit proxy. A transparent proxy is not explicitly configured in the client (i.e. *transparent* to the client). Anyway, what exactly is your problem - understanding how the CONNECT method work? Understanding how a proxy works? Inability to code it? ...